# Distinguish between leads that convert into a new vs existing opportunity

Tags: visual-workflow, lead-conversion

I need to distinguish between leads that are converted, and create new opportunities, and for converted leads into existing ones.

I created an After Convert flow: Pretty simple
[image]

What I am doing, is getting the converted opportunityID, from the lead: convertedopportunityid, and search if it exists on other converted leads.
Based if found or not, I update my code.

But I have a feeling the behaviour is not consistent, it could be because the DML transaction is not complete, Until only 'After the convert'.

Any ideas or limitations that I am missing here?

Comment: Leads can also be converted without creating an opportunity, or the opportunity could have been subsequently deleted, etc. Without testing this, my initial thought would be to check if the lead converted date equals the opportunity created date. When true, this is a new opportunity, when false, an existing opportunity.